# How do you deserialize static properties with YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, deserialization, yamldotnet

I'm having trouble deserializing yaml into static properties. When I try, I get the exception `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Property 'Test' not found on type 'Program+Config'.` This seems weird to me because I was successfully doing this before with a static IEnumerable of my objects (I needed to reorganize my file so I can't do this any more).  Has anyone successfully been able to do this?

A minimal example showing the problem:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Deserializer().Deserialize<Config>("Test: Value");
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public static string Test { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion - this should work if the Test property is not static and store the deserialized object with a static variable.

Comment: Now that you mention it, that was how I deserialized my file before.  While that would work, I've gone with making my fields non-static and spreading my config around via DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. This is not somethig that YamlDotNet supports and there are no plans to support it.